# Python: purpose of "else" in while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

My question is why there is such a thing as an "else" clause in a while loop. My code, for example, looks like this:

```
a = 100
turns = 0
while a > 0:
    if func(a, b): #Function returns boolean value
        a -= 1
        turns += 1
    else:
        a -= 2
        turns += 1
else:
    print(turns)
```

The question being, how is this any different from following syntax?

```
a = 100
turns = 0
while a > 0:
    if func(a, b): #Function returns boolean value
        a -= 1
        turns += 1
    else:
        a -= 2
        turns += 1
print(turns)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is how it handles abnormal exiting of the loop, e.g. a `break`:

```
while True:
    break
else:
    print("not printed")
print("printed")
```

The same applies to exceptions raised inside the loop body.